# How to escape mysql blank and duplicate data using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this code to send data to mysql database and its functioning well though users are sending blank data and duplicating too.

```
<?php 
  require "conn.php";
  $lostidno = $_POST ["lostidno"];
  $phonenol = $_POST ["phonenol"];

  $mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO lostdb.lost (lostidno, phonenol) VALUES ('$lostidno', '$phonenol')";  

  if ($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE) 
  {
    echo "Information Recieved!";
  }
  else
    echo "Sorry! An Error Occured:" . $mysql_qry . "br" . $conn->error;

  $conn->close();

?>
```

How do I prevent this?

Comment: Have you heard of **validation**?

Comment: Watch out for [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: By checking the condition. If condition gives true, then don't insert the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `trim` function to remove spaces at the beginning and the ending of a string. After that you are able to check if the two parameters aren't empty:

```
<?php 
require "conn.php";
$lostidno = trim($_POST["lostidno"]);
$phonenol = trim($_POST["phonenol"]);

if(!empty($lostidno) && !empty($phonenol))
{
    $mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO lostdb.lost (lostidno, phonenol) VALUES ('$lostidno', '$phonenol')";  

    if ($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE) {
        echo "Information Recieved!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Sorry! An Error Occured:" . $mysql_qry . "br" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

You should also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to prevent [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: this has prevented blank data but duplicates are still coming in.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. To avoid blank values

Check the values of variables before executing insert query on database using [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) PHP function.

### 2. Avoid duplicate values

You can do it in two ways, Either specify `UNIQUE` constriant in database `TABLE` or run `SELECT` query before inserting data into database.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this to check the duplicate records
Fire the select query : select * from lostdb.lost where col1= $lostidno and col2 = $phonenol;

//this is to check the blank condition
if($lostidno !== "" && $phonenol != "")
{
  $mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO lostdb.lost (lostidno, phonenol) VALUES ('$lostidno', '$phonenol')"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use trim function to remove blank spaces from string.

```
<?php 
require "conn.php";
$lostidno = trim($_POST ["lostidno"]);
$phonenol = trim($_POST ["phonenol"]);

//Check record exist or not.
$unique_check = "select count(*) as cnt from lostdb.lost where lostidno='".$lostidno."' and phonenol='".$phonenol."'";
//Execute above query and check record already exist or not. If record not exist then only allow to insert it.

$result_unique_check = $conn->query($mysql_qry)->one();
$record_exist = $result_unique_check['cnt'];

if($record_exist > 0){
    echo "Record alreay exist.";    
}else{
    //Insert new record
    $mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO lostdb.lost (lostidno, phonenol) VALUES ('$lostidno', '$phonenol')";  

    if ($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE) 
    {
    echo "Information Recieved!";
    }
    else

    echo "Sorry! An Error Occured:" . $mysql_qry . "br" . $conn->error;

    $conn->close();   
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to prevent duplicates is to mark the unique database columns as `UNIQUE`

`ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD UNIQUE(<column_name>);`

To prevent blank data from ever getting into the database you need to check them with a few modifications in the code you posted:

```
if( ($lostidnol != "") && ($phonenol != "") )
{
    if ($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE) 
    {
        echo "Information Recieved!";
    }
    else
    {
        //error
    }
}
else
{
    //Notify the user that they're trying to insert blanks
}
```

If you want to provide proper user experience you should also provide some client side validation using JavaScript or jQuery